# WordPress multiple sidebar is not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I may doing a silly mistake. I added two sidebars in my one function call. But, it's showing the first sidebar, but not showing the 2nd sidebar. Can't figure it out, where is the problem actually. I am using here `register_sidebar` function.

In **functions.php**

```
    function scilibrary_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array (
        'name' => 'About Us Sidebar Gutech',
        'id' => 'about_sidebar_gutech'
    )
    );

    register_sidebar( array (
        'name' => 'Services Sidebar Gutech',
        'id' => 'services_sidebar_gutech'
    )
   );


   }

   add_action('widgets_init', 'scilibrary_widgets_init');
```

**My front page code:**

```
                             <div id="sidebar-primary-2" class="gutech-sidebar">
                                <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'services_sidebar_gutech' ) ) : ?>
                                    <?php 
                                    dynamic_sidebar( 'services_sidebar_gutech' ); ?>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <!-- Time to add some widgets! -->
                                    <p> Widget is missing </p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
```

Can you see any mistakes I have done, can you please help me to figure it out?
Thanks.

Comment: You are calling only the first sidebar. You have to call second sidebar too.

Comment: @MartinMirchev Hi, yes, its working fine in my side also now. Strange. Last night, and this morning, it didn't work. Now working. Haha. Thanks.
Anyway, is my approach is good? I haven't added before widget,after widget etc.. in sidebar. Is that okay?

Comment: Its not a problem if you are okay with default ones. For SEO purposes sometimes i change title h tag .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want 2 sidebars in one container but you should do it like this

```
//Call first sidebar
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'about_sidebar_gutech' ) ) :
    dynamic_sidebar( 'about_sidebar_gutech' );
else :
    echo 'no sidebar';
endif; 
//Call second sidebar
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'services_sidebar_gutech' ) ) :
    dynamic_sidebar( 'services_sidebar_gutech' );
else :
    echo 'no sidebar';
endif;
```

Comment: Hi @MartinMirchev, actually I have two different template to use two different sidebars. That's why created two sidebars.